# Improving `IntersectionObserver` based lazy loading implementation

Tags: javascript, html, css, intersection-observer

I'm trying to implement lazy loading by setting up an observer to a `<footer>` element which is actually at the bottom of a page.

I've  set up the following options for the `IntersectionObserver` instance initialized:

```
  let intersectionOptions = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '150px',
    threshold: 0.15
  }

  const footer = document.querySelector('footer');
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, intersectionOptions);
```

Where callback is a following like:

```
 const callback = async (entries = [], observer) => {
    const [entry] = entries;
    let { isIntersecting, time } = entry;
    time = time/1000;
    const timeDelta = time - intersectionTimeStart;
    const worthTime = timeDelta > 0.5;
    const worthToTrigger = isIntersecting && worthTime;
    intersectionTimeStart = time;
    if (worthToTrigger) {
      options.observer = observer;
      options.element = entry.target;
      // lazy loading side effect
      await intersectionCallback(options);
    }
  }
```

The overall HTML looks like the following:

```
<CardList>
 <CardRow />
 <CardRow />
 <CardRow />
 <CardRow />
</CardList>
<Footer />
```

This implemented logic works great when user scrolls down slowly, and Footer would intersect with viewport, the way a new `CardRow` would be fetched and then rendered within `CardList` and placed at the bottom.

However, there's a main issue, if user would scroll down quickly, only one page would be paged, making necessary to scroll up and down again to fetch a new page, which is definitely funky.

I could remove the `worthTime` bit of logic however, it'd still need to have a way to fetch the page only once, unless user *tries* to scroll down again.

I definitely don't want to introduce an event listener for scroll event, as this would mean reimplementing.

Is there any straight forward solution for this case?